# How do I log depending on which task is run in grunt?

Tags: logging, gruntjs, task, target

TL:DR - Is it possible to check if a certain task/subtask is set to run when grunt is invoked? Something like

```
if(grunt.runningTasks.substr('task:subtask') > -1)
```

Original Question -

I have the following code in my karma.js for grunt. I want to know if it's possible to only execute the function for the task which is being run

I pull config from my gruntfile ( I'm using load-grunt-config ) and I want to log based on the task I'm running and whether --browser was entered or not

A sample run would be grunt karma:jenkins but this outputs logs for each target as the functions are called for each even though the jenkins target is the only one to run

How do I delay running my function until the target is actually invoked?

```
module.exports = function(grunt, config) {
//function to calculate which browser to use as default if one is not specified on the command-line
var returnBrowser = function (taskName ) {
    var defaults = config.defaultBrowsers,
        browser = config.testBrowser;
    if (!browser) {
        browser = defaults[taskName];
        if ( browser ) {
            grunt.log.writeln("No browser option set for unit tests, using " + browser + " which is default for karma:" + taskName + " task.");
            grunt.log.writeln("Use --browser=<chrome || firefox || ie> to set a specific browser");
        } else {
            grunt.log.writeln("No browser option set for unit tests and task karma:" + taskName + " does not have a default browser specified. Defaulting to IE");
            grunt.log.writeln("Use --browser=<chrome || firefox || ie> to set a specific browser");
            browser = defaults['default'];
        }
    }
    return [browser];
}
return {
    options: {
        configFile: 'karmastandalone.conf.js',
        singleRun: true,
        autoWatch: false,
        reporters: ['progress']
    },
    test: { 
        browsers: returnBrowser('test')
    },
    jenkins: {
        browsers: returnBrowser('jenkins'),
        options: {
            reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],
            junitReporter: {
                outputFile: '<%= junitOutputFile %>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

};

Comment: I'm a little confused... is that JS module a custom grunt task you're trying to run?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is the grunt-karma task. I'm using load-grunt-config which allows you to break config up in to separate files so this file would be karma.js and it exports its conf as either an object or a function. You can check out the project for more details on this approach

Comment: Aaah... gotcha. Okay, sooo, I think you can do what you're asking, but not just with config as far as I know. I'm not at my main computer, but I'll try to show an example using a custom task when I'm at my desk.

Comment: Hmm... not sure about a full solution, but to your first question, you can use the [grunt API](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.exists) for determining if a task exists: `grunt.task.exists('task:subtask')` (although I haven't used it for subtasks). And you can get a command line option using: `grunt.option('browser')`

Comment: Thanks, I know the task exists however, I'm hoping to be able to tell if a task will be invoked by the current alias (i.e. if default contains karma or a task that in turn contains karma when grunt is run)

Comment: Aaaah, yeah... answer incoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so following the path of the comments above, I see what the OP is asking for more clearly now. Unfortunately, there is no publicly exposed API for this as far as I know. However, you can access this information from the `grunt` object passed into the various modules.

In the example below I have a simple `build` task which, as you can see, is an alias for two other tasks, one of which has a target (subtask) specified. If I need to know if a given task has a specific subtask specified I can do so like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat:js', 'uglify']);

grunt.registerTask('isjsbuild', function() {
    var info = grunt.task._tasks['build'].info;
    // 'info' in this case would be: "Alias for \"concat:js\", \"uglify\" tasks."

    if (/^Alias.+?concat\:js/.test(info)) {
        grunt.log.writeln('we have concat:js in an alias!');

        // do whatever you need to here...
    }
});
```

There are some obvious caveats here: first of which is that **this is an undocumented, internal object!** That means it could change at any time, so *use with caution*.

Also, I'm running this as it's own task. If you run it inside that dynamic config module you have I'm not sure how it will perform. Additionally, this is not using any input, but you can get CLI options using `grunt.option('whatever')` if need be. Lastly, this doesn't assume that the give task (`build`) is actually in the queue, it's just getting the info based on the current config, so you may want to check that the given task is in the queue with something like: `grunt.task.exists('build');`

Hope this helps!
(In case you're curious, I gleaned this from the [Grunt source code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/d47c75543b09218be95869eed4c285d6044b538b/lib/grunt/help.js#L92).)

Comment: Thanks a million, more than enough for me to muddle through from here. P.S. Love the Hobbes avatar :)

Comment: Yay! Glad we finally figured out what you needed. I _was_ Calvin growing up, and even had a stuffed tiger. :)